# Most effective way to manage a growing list of time series data in an MS Access database

Tags: database-design, performance, ms-access, query-performance

I am building a database to store time series data along with some other summary statistics. Since this is a local application I do not have access to more robust database solutions and am confined to the MS Access 2013 offering. I was trying to manage the work as a flat table in excel but this becomes unworkable. Each run consists of 6 trials each having a handful of metrics (say 7) important pieces of information.

My issue arises from the fact that I have time series information associated in the run that I would like to store and query for plotting. The size of the scatter data ranges from 10,000-50,000 points. I was thinking to have access query excel, but I would like the response to be somewhat snappy. The intent is to be able to compare different runs and simply pulling data in as needed.

*** UPDATE ***
I am using this database to store runs from lab equipment. The dataset comes in x,y pairs and have array lengths up to 50,000 points. I will have more and more sets to add to the database.

Where I am stuck is I am not sure how to get the data into access in a smart way. I was thinking about adding field for each dataset but that seemms stupid and obviously I cannot do a muli-valued field for this.

snip of data in excel 
[image: epic of Data in excel]

Comment: Have you looked at SQL Express?

Comment: It is difficult to provide specific advice without additional details.  What does your sample data look like?  Is Excel having problems with the current data amounts?

Comment: @AliRazeghi I updated my post with more information. Any ideas would be much appreciated I am at a complete loss

Comment: MS Access has the ability to import files, assuming the format is the same you can save the definition of the import. If there is a huge number of these files you could and  automate this with macro. Otherwise look at sql express and bcp or ssis to import.

Comment: SQLExpress let's you import a CSV file very easily, or you could script it out as Peter mentioned in BCP.  SQLExpress will be a lot faster and flexible than Access and is free.  See: https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/importing-csv-file-into-your-database-with-sql-server.aspx  and   http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/28/four-easy-ways-to-import-csv-files-to-sql-server-with-powershell.aspx